# Transitivity guarantee for transparent comparisons in associative containers

Tags: c++, std

Assume we have an ordered container with custom `Key` and transitive comparator `Less`, and we do lookup in it, like this:

```
struct Key {
    int a, b;
    auto operator <=> (const Key&) const noexcept = default;
};

struct Less {
    bool operator ()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) const noexcept {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }

    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator ()(const Key& lhs, int rhs) const noexcept {
        return lhs.a < rhs;
    }
    bool operator ()(int lhs, const Key& rhs) const noexcept {
        return lhs < rhs.a;
    }
};

set<Key, Less> s = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}};
auto [begin, end] = s.equal_range(2);
```

Now the question: is `s.equal_range(2)` guaranteed by c++ standard to return range containing elements `{2, 1}, {2, 2}` or is there some transitivity-based UB?

In other words: are standard guarantees/requirements for transparent transitivity any different from guarantees/requirements for key transitivity in ordered containers?

Comment: Indeed, your `Less` doesn't respect strict weak ordering. (`2 <=> {2, 1}`, `2 <=> {2, 2}`, but `{2, 1} < {2, 2}`).

Comment: Well elements sorted lexicographically by `a, b` obviously remain sorted by `a`, so if that was a sorted vector instead, I'd be good. But I actually found the case where difference in transparency makes difference in output with libc++'s `std::map`, so I wonder if that is according to standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.equal_range(ke)` is defined as equivalent to `std::make_­pair( s.lower_­bound(ke), s.upper_­bound(ke));`

and `std::set` should be partitioned according to `comp(x, ke)` and `!comp(ke, x)` (and `c(x, ke)` implying `!c(ke, x)`).

See [container.requirements#associative.reqmts.general-8](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#associative.reqmts.general-8) for formal requirements.

So in your case your are good as

```
{{1, 1}, {1, 2},   {2, 1}, {2, 2},   {3, 1}, {3, 2}}
//        x < 2  |    !(x < 2)
//                    !(2 < x)     |    2 < x
//
```